# Maven could not create local repository

Tags: java, spring, maven

Here's a problem. I renamed my User folder in windows where was .m2 folder.
So now I'm getting this error both in idea and eclipse:

```
[ERROR] Could not create local repository at C:\Users\Олег\.m2\repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException
```

This is the old path

> C:\Users\Олег\.m2\repository

and this is the new one

> C:\Users\Oleg\.m2\repository

I've tried everything. Removing maven. Removing all cache folders. Changed path in settings file in maven. Changed path in plugins in idea and eclipse. Reinstall both idea and eclipse.

But still I can't run any spring app I'm getting either this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

or when I add maven dependency in deployment assembly I'm getting that error I mentioned above.

Maybe someone faced this problem.

Thanks

Update: My fault. I had to explain better. I changed user name in a proper way. In administrator user and with changing registry and other stuff

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Websystems</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>Websystems Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <springCoreVersion>3.2.4.RELEASE</springCoreVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springCoreVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springCoreVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springCoreVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springCoreVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springCoreVersion}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>    
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>Websystems</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please add your pom.xml in order to give you a solution

Comment: does folder C:\Users\Oleg.m2 exist? I don't think maven has the privileges to just create random folders in C:\Users\

Comment: Try this https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/change-local-repository-location/

Comment: yes it's exists. and I've already tried to change path in settings.xml but this didn't work

Comment: ouch, why should someone rename his user folder (without renaming the user ...and expect anything to still work)

Comment: I did it in the right way, not just right click and rename

Comment: but to solve your issue: What is the output of `echo %USERPROFILE%` ? ..and please check: maven installation/conf folder as your IDE (maven) settings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually renaming your user folder (without renaming the user) I regard for a "bold idea", but to fix this particular issue i think this (alternatives) can help:

1. "Hack" `%USERPROFILE%` in cmd:

   ```
   SET USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Oleg
   ```

   in command line, before each `mvn` invocation. (needs to be executed on each new `cmd`, can also be done permanently via `SETX`, but probably causes many side effects.)
2. Rename your user... (cleaner but can cause subordinate issues...)
3. Create a `settings.xml` file in `C:\Users\Олег\.m2` with the following element:

   ```
   <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
       <localRepository>C:\Users\Oleg\.m2\repository</localRepository>

       ...
    </settings>
   ```
4. Alternative 3. can also be applied globally (same content): In `%MAVEN_HOME%/conf/settings.xml` (this is probably the best and least intrusive choice for you.)
5. ..

I'd be happy, if this fixes your maven, but I forsee "other/more issues" and strongly recommend **not** to "hack(=manually rename) your user directory" (in no OS).

Comment: thanks. I think adding settings.xml in .m2 folder helped me. I'm still can't run my little app. But there's no old errors

Comment: :( ..concentrate on 4. and your IDE(s) settings, @Skyglar

Comment: ..especially IDEs when it is "embedded maven" ...and what else might "manipulate" your user_name, user_home...